# Convert datetime in java

Tags: java

I have to convert datetime from one format to another in java. Here is the period im starting with:

```
2001-01-01T01:00Z/2002-02-02T02:00Z
```

and here is the result i need to end up with:

```
2002-02-02T02:00:00
```

So basically i need the second part of the period and i need to add `:00` as seconds to the end and remove the Z.

Im not really familiar with date formats. Is one of these a standard format? Can i use some kind of library to read and convert these datetimes?

Comment: If you're using Java version 8, look into the `java.time` package. If you´re using a previous version, look into the joda-time library.

Comment: @Henrik It's `java.time`, not `java.util.time`.

Comment: What a rookie mistake .... Embarrassing. Thanks.

Comment: @Henrik No, if using Java 6 or 7, use the [*ThreeTen-Backport*](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project rather than Joda-Time.  The Joda-Time project is now in maintenance mode.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
Interval.parse( input ) 
        .getEnd()
        .atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) 
        .format(
            DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME 
        )
```

## `Interval`

Your input string for the period is on standard [ISO 8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. It represents a pair of moments, where the `Z` on the end is short for Zulu and means UTC. The slash character separates the start and stop.

Parse those with the [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html) class found in the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project.

```
Interval interval = Interval.parse( input ) ;
```

## `Instant`

Extract the stop moment.

```
Instant instant = interval.getEnd() ;
```

## `OffsetDateTime`

I suspect you should be working with objects like `Instant` rather than manipulating the String. But if you insist, for generating a formatted string, convert the `Instant` to a `OffsetDateTime`.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = instant.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

Also, it is usually a bad idea to drop the offset/zone indicator such as the `Z`. The resulting string becomes ambiguous as to its meaning, no longer representing a specific moment on the timeline. But if you insist, there is a predefined for matter.

```
String output = odt.format( DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME ) ;
```